# SAS Program: What is the problem of this additional column pointer @1 at the Variable ID?

Tags: sas

Add @1 in the Input ID and ANS (Wrong Program):

```
DATA SCORE;

ARRAY KEY[10] $ 1 _TEMPORARY_;
ARRAY ANS[10] $ 1;
IF _N_ = 1 THEN
    DO I=1 TO 10;
        INPUT KEY[I] @;
    END;
INPUT  @1 ID $ @5 (ANS1-ANS10) ($1.);
RAWSCORE = 0;
DO I=1 TO 10;
    RAWSCORE = RAWSCORE + (ANS[I] EQ KEY[I]);
END;
PERCENT = 100*RAWSCORE/10;
DROP I;
DATALINES;
A B C D E E D C B A
001 ABCDEABCDE
002 AAAAABBBBB
;
PROC PRINT DATA=SCORE;
   TITLE "SCORE Data Set";
   ID ID;
   VAR RAWSCORE PERCENT;
RUN;
```

This is a program from the book <Applied statistics and the SAS programming language> Chapter 15.

The original program from the textbook, there is no @1 at the INPUT statement for ID, it will give the desired output; If I added a column pointer at ID as shown below, it will read the key, the first dataline again, even though there exists a IF THEN statement and uses *N* to test whether it is the first dataline.

Can anyone explain what is the problem of this column @1, and why @5 is fine with this program?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing another INPUT statement.

On the first iteration of the data step you first run 10 INPUT statements with trailing @.  So you are still on the first line.

Since the program does not use the TRUNCOVER (or even the ancient MISSOVER) option the default action of FLOW OVER will apply.  In which case as long as there is not an eleventh KEY value on the first line the INPUT statement without the pointer motion control will skip to the second line when it does not find anything at the end of the first line to satisfy the input of ID.  There should be a note in the SAS LOG saying that INPUT had to move to new line.

```
NOTE: SAS went to a new line when INPUT statement reached past the end of a line
```

If you add the @1 then on the first iteration of the data step that will move the pointer from after the last KEY value back to the first column. Which cause it to read the first KEY value as the ID instead.  On the other iterations the @1 has no impact since that is the default location for the pointer at the start of an iteration.

It is probably worth being more explicit about when you are done with the first line.

```
IF _N_ = 1 THEN DO;
    DO I=1 TO 10;
        INPUT KEY[I] @;
    END;
    INPUT;
END;
INPUT ID $ @5 (ANS1-ANS10) ($1.);
```

Now adding pointer motion to move to the first column will not have any impact.

Comment: Hi Tom, Thank you! Your answer makes sense to me. I just want to clarify a few more things: 1. In the textbook, we only use the TRUNCOVER or MISSOVER in an INFILE statement. How will these options be applied in this pure INPUT statement?

Comment: 2. I feel like I am confused at the single trailing @. In the textbook, it says 'A single @ sign will hold the line. That is, do not move the pointer to the next record until an INPUT statement without a trailing @ is reached or until the next iteration of the DATA step begins.' For this program, if we coded as INPUT  @1 ID $ @5 (ANS1-ANS10) ($1.), does this mean the single trailing @ still holds the line because of the first @1?  Therefore in the program you provided, you add an additional loop and an additional input?

Comment: You can use `infile datalines ....;` to add INFILE options to a data step with in-line data. The trailing `@` on an INPUT statement only effects the behavior of that particular INPUT statement.  If you have a second INPUT statement without a trailing `@` then the line is "released".  Read up on the meaning of a double trailing `@@`.  Also pointer control also uses the `@` character but it is a completely different thing than a trailing `@`.

Comment: Thank you. If the point control's @ is different from the single trailing's @, how 'INPUT @1 ID' won't release the line while 'INPUT ID 'will release the line to the second data line?

Comment: It did release the line, but since you don't run any more INPUT statements after that you cannot tell. Reread my answer to see why it works without the @1 and why it fails with the @1.

Comment: I'm sorry. I think there's still some confusion between "release a record held by a trailing @" and "skip and move to the second line."  Does the release holder mean the same thing as moving the holder to the second line? Thank you for your patience, I want to make sure I fully understand this.

Comment: Yes.  Release the line means it is gone and the pointer is now positioned ready to start reading the next line at the beginning.

Comment: Then `INPUT  @1 ID $ @5 (ANS1-ANS10) ($1.)` will release the line and skip to the second line, why the column pointer will be at the first data line, column 1?

Comment: At the end of an iteration of the data step the line currently being read is released. I asked you read up on trailing `@@`.  That is the only way that the pointer at the start of an iteration of the data step will not be pointing at the first column.  With trailing `@@` not only is the line not released the pointer is also not reset to column one. Instead the pointer stays where it was when it ran the input with the trailing `@@`.

Comment: I think I understand double trailing. I am just confused by `INPUT  @1 ID $ @5 (ANS1-ANS10) ($1.)`. We do not use either single trailing or double trailing here, so why are we still reading the first data line, the keys, from the first column,  instead of reading the second data line even though the holder is released? Thank you!

Comment: Huh?  You seem to have the order of operations reversed.  The statements in a data step are executed in order.  So when the INPUT @1 statement runs the current line has not YET been released.

Comment: OK. Let me rephrase this to check if I have understood:  After I have read all the 10 keys by `INPUT KEY[I] @;`, the pointer is still held at the end of the first line. 1) Now, If we execute the  `INPUT @1 ID`, it will move the pointer to the first column first,  if so we still have data that can be read from the first line, we will reread the keys; 2) If we use `INPUT ID` instead, since the pointer is not relocated and will stay at the end of the first line, and there is no more data to read in from the first line, then the holder is released and we skip to the second line. Am I correct?

Comment: You got it exactly.